# Extract n-th field from string using regex in Simulink m-function

Tags: regex, matlab, simulink

I'm using Simulink to process some strings that are sent from remote server over TCP/IP in real-time. The string (in form of ASCII integers) I'm getting in Simulink every few miliseconds is this (comma separated fields):

```
$FORMAT,YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6*XX
```

where fields1-3 and field5 and field6 are strings. XX is XOR checksum.
***Field3* tells me what is the name of the value and *Field4* has some integer value and these two are the fields I need to extract with regex.** How do I do that?

P.S.: In Simulink (2016a) on the receiving side I have TCP/IP Receive block and the string gets processed in Simulink's m-function, so it has some limitation from regular Matlab file (for example `strsplit` method doesn't work here)

Comment: Can any of the fields contain commas?

Comment: No. Field contains numbers, a dot for floating point and chars from A-Z, no commas.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what kind of regexes Simulink’s “m-function” supports, but if you can extract [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with it, you can match each field easily. Here’s a regex for that with expanded whitespace and comments, for the purposes of understanding:

```regex
^          # start of the line
[^,]* ,    # format
[^,]* ,    # date
[^,]* ,    # field1
[^,]* ,    # field2
([^,]*) ,  # field3 in capture group 1
([^,]*) ,  # field4 in capture group 2
           # we don’t need to match any more fields; we have the two we want
```

And here it is in compact form:

```regex
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),([^,]*),
```

Match capture groups 1 and 2 (`matches[1]`, `$1`, however you do that in your environment) to get the contents of field3 and field4.